# Hibernate Converter Causes SQLException

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, converters

In my Hibernate entity class I have a Boolean that I want to be true for certain characters in a column of `VARCHAR2(1)`. But my code causes a `SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation`. Can someone see what I'm doing wrong? My code is as follows:

In my entity I have:

```
...

    private Boolean flag;

    @Column(length = 1, name = "FLAG")
    @Convert(converter = FlagToBooleanConverter.class)
    public Boolean getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }

    void setFlag(Boolean flag)
    {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

...

@Converter
class FlagToBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String>
{
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value)
    {
        return (value.equals("X") || value.equals("Y"));
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(String value)
    {
        // My class should only read from the DB so I don't need this but I have to override it
        return null;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Feels kind of hacky, but at the moment, to get the job down I've been using:

```
    private String flag;

    @Column(length = 1, name = "FLAG")
    String getFlag()
    {
        return flag;
    }

    void setFlag(String flag)
    {
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @Transient
    public Boolean isFlag()
    {
        return (value.equals("X") || value.equals("Y"));
    }
```

Comment: You should be using `value.equals("X") || ...` instead of `==`.  The `convertToEntityAttribute` method will always return `false` as its coded now.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287694/how-to-compare-different-language-string-values-in-java

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't fix the prevailing problem but that probably saves me a headache down the line.

Comment: What if the value is `null`? `"X".equals(value) || "Y".equals(value)` will deal with that case. And if you create the DDL with Hibernate I would guess that you will have to define the column type with `@Column(name="FLAG", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(1)")`

Comment: Why are you sure that you can simply return `null` from the `convertToDatabaseColumn` method?

Comment: No, but I get the same error if I don't return null.