# Localized (Double) Metaphone for Portuguese (pt_PT)

Tags: php, localization, soundex, non-english, metaphone

I want to see how phonetically similar two non-English strings are, AFAIK [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) and [metaphone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) implementations only work correctly for English based strings, for instance [`coração` and `corassão`](http://translate.google.com/#en%7Cpt%7Ccora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20corass%C3%A3o) sound exactly the same in Portuguese but `metaphone()` returns [`KR` and `KRS`](http://codepad.org/I2cSVOcf). The same thing happens with other phonemes, [`chita` and `xita`](http://translate.google.com/#en|pt|chita%20xita) returns [`XT` and `ST`](http://codepad.org/yFiBoSuk), but they sound the same.

I've also tried this [Double Metaphone implementation](http://swoodbridge.com/DoubleMetaPhone/) ([demo](http://swoodbridge.com/DoubleMetaPhone/mptest.php3)) but the results are exactly the same.

So, **is there any alternative algorithm that works with Portuguese words**? I've [read about Lucene in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1420064/89771), but I've never used it before and I'm not sure how it works or how to use it.

If not, does anyone know what kind of data I need to gather to develop a metaphone-like algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, I found a promising work-in-progress [here](http://code.google.com/p/metaphone-standards/) and [some](http://sourceforge.net/projects/metaphoneptbr/) [other](http://mecanicamente.blogspot.pt/2009/10/metaphone-em-portugues-para-java.html) [cool](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/metaphoneptbr/) [projects](https://github.com/ruliana/MTFN).