# Lucene(QueryParser) in Java

Tags: java, lucene

I create query by QueryParser:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "Text", new RussianAnalayzer());
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
Query query = parser.parse(searchString);
```

When I use the phrase where the words have variations, I'm getting the united with "AND", like: "term1 term2" -> "term1 AND "term2_1 AND term2_2"". 
How can I get query like : "term1 AND "term2_1 OR term2_2"" without splitting string for words?

Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand you.  How is term2 split into multiple terms?  Is it just a list of terms stored in a variable that you're talking about, something like:
    term1 = "term1"
    term2 = "term2_1 term2_2"
    query = term1 + " " + term2;

Or is it really only two terms, which are split up automatically (by the analyzer or something perhaps)?

At any rate, I think it would probably serve your purpose to change the second line given to:

```
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);
//Or just delete this line if you prefer, OR is the default behavior.
```

and pass a query that makes sense given that behavior, such as:

```
"term1 AND (term2)"
```

Which is, presumably, equivalent to:

```
"term1 AND (term2_1 term2_2)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. RussianAnalayzer() converts term2 in variation(normal form) of this word in russian language like : красная -> красная красный. And when I give sentence for Lucene I need get a result query like union all the word of sentence but variant of word must be union by OR. When I give a sentence I don't know which of the word have variant. If I put AND in sentence manually and then give in QueryParser whith DefaultOperator OR in result I get all the same "term1 AND "term2_1 AND term2_2""

Comment: That sounds like an issue with the RussianStemmer, I think.  I'm noticing some complaints about the RusianAnalyzer, I'd see if you see the same issue using a different analyzer.  A couple of alternatives are posted in answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63896/analyzer-for-russian-language-in-lucene-and-lucene-net

Comment: Just for fun, you could also try using '+' instead of 'and', like "+term1 +term2" instead of "term1 AND term2", but those two should be identical, and I have no reason to believe it would work any differently.  Just might be worth a quick look.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For this time the best alternative for me it's that I had override the QueryParser. (Different way is to use RussianLuceneMorphology and not use QueryParser)